# Restrict a page for admin only

Tags: php, redirect, admin, roles

I've redirected the non-admin who try to access the employee.php to user.php, however, the admin role also gets redirected to the user.php.
Note: The $_SESSION['ID'] was created on the login page to set permission. There's 2 types of role: Admin and user.

```
        <?php

        if(!isset($_SESSION['ID']) &&( $_SESSION['ROLE'] != 'admin') )
        {
            header("Location:user.php"); //Do not allow him to access.
            exit;
        }

         session_start();
        if(!$_SESSION['username']){
            header("Location:login.php"); 
        }

        ?>
```

I've tried this too.

```
        <?php

        if(!isset($_SESSION['ID']) &&( $_SESSION['ROLE'] != 'admin') )
        {
            header("Location:user.php"); 
            exit;
        }
        else{
            header("Location:employee.php");
            exit;}

         session_start();
        if(!$_SESSION['username']){
            header("Location:login.php"); 
        }
       
        ?>
```

Login: code.php

```
        if(isset($_POST['login_btn']))
    {
        $email_login=$_POST['email'];
        $password_login=$_POST['password'];

    if (!empty($email_login) || !empty($password_login)) {
        $query="SELECT * FROM register WHERE email=? AND pwd=?";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email_login,$password_login);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();  // get the mysqli result

            if($result->num_rows > 0){       
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  
                $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['ROLE'] = $row['usertype'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                
                if($_SESSION['ROLE'] == 'admin'){ 
                header("Location:index.php");
                die(); }
                else{ 
                    header("Location:user.php");
                    die(); }
                }
        else{
            $_SESSION['status']='Email ID or Password is incorrect';
            header("Location:login.php");
        }
    }    
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['status']='Email ID or Password is Insert';
            header("Location:login.php");
        }   
    }
```

Unfortunately, the result is the same. Any Solution?

Comment: what are u getting for isset($_SESSION['ID'] when u try the admin role

Comment: We can't see the contents of your session variable so it's hard to comment on what the expected behaviour would be. What debugging have you done, to try and verify what the session contains? Also what does the session.php code do, exactly? Maybe show us that.

Comment: does the currently edited post help for better understanding?  @JaisonThomas

Comment: @ADyson session.php only contained   session_start(); and redirect to login page if not logged in. I've included that in the edited post.

Comment: have u tried to echo $_SESSION['ROLE'] to see if the result comes as admin ?

Comment: `session.php only contained session_start(); `...ok, well you need to make sure you include that _before_ you try to use any session variables in the script, otherwise they will not be accessible

Comment: @JaisonThomas Yes, i tried. It showed admin

Comment: @ADyson if i do that, user account still have access to employee.php

Comment: Ok well that's just the first step. After that you need to debug it as I mentioned earlier, and check the values in the $_session variable correspond to what you expected at each moment, or not. Report some sample values to us, then we can advise you. You can use the var_dump or var_export functions to output the data.

Comment: P.s. think about this...when your login code runs, if the user successfully logs in then you are setting the ID value in the session. That makes sense. But then your logic for the admin user says it can only redirect to user.php when the ID is **not** set. I think that probably isn't what you intended? It makes no sense that the role would be set to admin but the ID would not be set at all, that cannot occur.